# Put a view in the bottom of another view with a fixed size

Tags: xcode, ios6, interface-builder, storyboard, autolayout

Sorry folks if my question seems to be trivial, but xcode drives me crazy.

I don't want anything else, just put a view in the bottom of a view controller in XCode by IB, that has FIXED height even if I rotate device. It stay simply in the bottom and its size stays unchanged.

Autolayout constraints changes its size all the time, hides if I rotate etc. I could not find the settings for this simple problem.

I need this (with fixed size, that does not change/hide when rotating):
[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried unchecking autolayout and playing around with autosizing. Try the below setting . It should work.

[image]